# Reset text fields in form fieldset

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form with two fieldsets which in turn have input text boxes.

```
<form id= "form1" class= "form">

<fieldset id="abc">

<input type = "text" name="a">
<input type = "text" name="b">

</fieldset>

<fieldset id="xyz">

<input type = "text" name="x">
<input type = "text" name="y">
<input type = "text" name="z">
</fieldset>


</form>
```

I would appreciate if someone could help me with a javascript which will reset the input boxes of fieldset "xyz" without changing values in input boxes in fieldset"abc".

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select elements under fieldset by selecting id of fieldset

```
$("#xyz > input").val("");
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/aodzvya7/)

Comment: Your code works fine with button press but on tab press does not work http://jsfiddle.net/aodzvya7/1/

Comment: You could ask new question for that

Comment: asked and recd answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26315497/reset-text-fields-in-form-fieldset-on-bootstrap-tab-press  but even that for some reason was not working in my app, so I added a class to all input and added $("#xyz .input-class").val(""); This worked..

Comment: if input is is not first child of the field set then you could try $("#xyz input").val(""); see http://jsfiddle.net/aodzvya7/3/