# Reset text fields in form fieldset on bootstrap tab press

Tags: javascript, jquery

This question is in context to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26314930/reset-text-fields-in-form-fieldset/)..

Html code :

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#a" data-toggle="tab">A</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#b" data-toggle="tab">B</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="a">
        <form id="form1" class="form">
            <fieldset id="abc">
                <input type="text" name="a">
                <input type="text" name="b">
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset id="xyz">
                <input type="text" name="x">
                <input type="text" name="y">
                <input type="text" name="z">
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="b"></div>
</div>
```

Javascript code:

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
               $("#xyz > input").val("");
            });
```

This does not work even though something similar does work on button press..

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aodzvya7/1/)

any help is sincerely appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to register the `shown.bs.tab` event handler once the DOM is ready:

```
$(function () {
  $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    $("#xyz > input").val("");
  });      
});
```

Otherwise the `on` is trying to bind a handler to an empty list of elements.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aodzvya7/2/)

Answer (score 0):

This will find all inputs within a specific fieldset via fieldset id attribute it will traverse all input fields inside a div or outside and clear them all when you toggle.

```
 $('a[data-toggle="tabs"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
        $("#fieldset_ID").find(':input').each(function() {
            $(this).val('');
        });
    });
```